# Pass variables from pelicanconf.py to markdown in Pelican

Tags: python, markdown, pelican

Is there a way to pass Python variables from pelicanconf.py to markdown page in [Pelican](https://blog.getpelican.com/)?

Thanks!

Comment: Markdown doesn't support anything like that. Such a feature would need to be a custom add-on. Pelican supports [plugins](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins) and Python-Markdown (the Markdown parser used by Pelican) supports [extensions](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/index.html). Perhaps there is a solution that works, but tool recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: This would generally be done in the *theme*, not the *content*. Could you give some more context around what you're trying to do?

Comment: For example in legal notice reusing `AUTHOR`, `SITEURL`,  `SITENAME`…